# How to actually calculate Pairwise Transient Key?

Tags: wireless, key-generation

I have following information:

**PTK-Pairwise Transient Key:** A value derived from PMK, Authenicator nonce(Anonce), Supplicant nonce(Snonce), Authenticator Address, Supplicant Address. This is used to encrypt all unicast transmission between client & an AP. PTK consist of 5 different keys. They are:

**1. KCK -** Key Confirmation Key used to provide data integrity during 4 -Way Handshake & Group Key Handshake.

**2. KEK –** Key Encryption Key used by EAPOL-Key frames to provide data privacy during 4-Way Handshake & Group Key Handshake.

**3. Temporal Key –** used to encrypt & decrypt MSDU of 802.11 data frames between supplicant & authenticator

**4. Temporal MIC-1**

**5. Temporal MIC-2**

And also, my lecture slides says:

> PTK = HMAC_SHA_1(PMK ||
>   AP_nonce || STAnonce ||
>   AP_MACaddr || STA_MACaddr)

Now my question is, how can I actually calculate PTK if following keys are given?

KCK = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"

KEK = "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"

TK = "cccccccccccccccc"

Comment: This question is too old to migrate, but it really belongs on crypto.stackexchange.com, where this may be the answer you seek:  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47003/how-pairwise-transient-key-is-derived-or-generated

Answer (score 1):

The PTK is split on the 5 keys you mentioned.

- 16 bytes for KCK
- 16 bytes for KEK
- 16 bytes for TK
- 8 bytes for MIC-1 key for transmitting
- 8 bytes for MIC-2 key for receiving

To recreate the PTK you need to have all the above values. I believe you are missing the latter 2 keys.